Garage dry wall to floor question
Garage wall to floor
Hi experts -  I’m early stages of modernizing older drywall in the garage and there’s some bare spots about 6-8 inches from the ground where cinder block meets cement.
What is the best practice to seal from the dry wall to the floor where cinder block is exposed?

from stud to stud

There might be a reason for that. For example puddles forming there

I don't think you want the drywall resting on the concrete floor.  There should be a gap of some amount.

My solution for my basement was to stop the drywall about 2" above floor level, to avoid wicking up any moisture on the floor, and cover the remaining gap with baseboards made out of 1x4 pressure treated lumber (which can tolerate getting wet occasionally).
